# Generate 3d regular spaced grid points on 3d surface of a building

Tags: mesh

I have a 3d city model that consist of 1282 buildings. I want to create points on these building surfaces as in the attaching pictureI want to generate points as regular spaced. Is there an algorithm or method for this purpose. I have vertice coordinates of buildings is it possible to generate points using ese coordinates? [image: points on building surfaces]. .

Comment: Maybe you could use a particle system?

Comment: What do you mean "*create points on these building surfaces*"? Do you mean like colors or textures over its surface? Or do you mean actual 3D points in scene space? Or do yu want to array other objecs over the surfaces?